# defining cron jobs with Cakephp 3.6

Tags: php, cakephp, cron, cakephp-3.6

I'm trying to setup a cron job to run a console command every minute.

```
class RescanCommand extends Command {

public function sendMail() {
    $email = new Email();

    // Sample SMTP configuration.
    Email::setConfigTransport('mailtrap', [
        'host' => 'smtp.mailtrap.io',
        'port' => 25,
        'username' => 'username',
        'password' => 'pass',
        'className' => 'Smtp'
    ]);

    $email->setFrom(['test@test.com' => 'CSV file'])
        ->setTo('test@test.com')
        ->setSubject('CSV Link File')
        ->send('Please find attached a copy of the links');
}

public function execute(Arguments $args, ConsoleIo $io) {
    $this->sendMail();
}
}
```

I can run the above code from command line by

> bin/cake rescan execute

and I receive the test email, but after creating a cron job by editing cron tabs like

> crontab -e

and inside the file by writing

> */1 * * * * cd /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/music && bin/cake Rescan execute

nothing happens, I was expecting to receive emails every minute,

can anyone please help find out what I'm doing wrong.

Thanks

Comment: first look at cli-errors log, cd corect path to app folder and && bin/cake Rescan execute where rescan  need to be lowercase.

Comment: @Salines there's nothing in the cli-errors log, I checked the path and it's correct and change the Rescan to lowercase, but still not receiving anything.

Comment: @Salines I'm using Cakephp built in server, does the crontab -e make the cronjob to run at the built in server?

Comment: "The software utility cron is a time-based job scheduler in Unix-like computer operating systems." . Your "web server" must contain httpserver , mysql, cron / sheduletask, and other software. CakePHP bulit in  server is't  http server. Why not try web development with  https://www.vagrantup.com/ ?

Comment: Check this [Cron Jobs on Shared Hosting](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/console-and-shells/cron-jobs.html)

Comment: @amir, if you run "bin/cake rescan execute" means you're already in the app directory, what happens when you run "cd /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/music && bin/cake Rescan execute", does it work?

Comment: @Yevgeniy It works, it sends the email as expected.

Comment: @amir I had an issue with running cake/bake from post-receive hooks — it turned out that it requires sudo, may be you have a similar issue? I would add echo or log for this task to see if it's running at all. If it runs and logs data, then try adding the script to sudo. I added: user_name ALL=(ALL:ALL) NOPASSWD:/full_path/bin/cake to /etc/sudoers on ubuntu and that solved my issue